# How to install shower speaker

Tags: shower

I recently bought a [shower speaker](http://www.fabfurnish.com/ENRG-Shower-Speaker-173642.html) from fabfurnish.com worth Rs.3,490..Does anyone know how to install this speaker exactly??
this is how it looks: [image]

Comment: Didn't the speaker come with installation instructions?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the information on that page and interpolating a bit:

This is a Bluetooth speaker in a waterproof case, plus a modified shower head that it can lock into. Remove the existing showerhead and replace it with the new one (the big object). Charge the speaker (the small object), turn it on (the button), and pair it with a device that can play to a Bluetooth headset/speaker/whatever. Confirm that it plays, then mount the speaker into the showerhead by pushing it into place and rotating 30 degrees (twist-lock). When you're done using it, push the button to turn it off and save battery power.

Note that if you don't have an MP3 player or radio that speaks Bluetooth, or some other way to get the audio into Bluetooth radio packets, you can't use this speaker.

Answer (score 0):

"How to install exactly": 
This shower head [image]

is designed to thread on to a fitting with 1/2" NPT (pipe thread) male threads, such as a standard threaded shower arm

[image]

use teflon tape or pipe thread sealer and screw it directly to the threaded arm. If your shower arm pipe does not look like this (there are many configurations that exist) you will have to remove your pipe/arm and change it with the threaded type (or maybe adapt what you have).

Comment: I presumed the question was largely about the speaker rather than the plumbing -- but you've covered the plumbing end of it better than I did. Thanks!

Comment: @keshlam, no worries! You are probably right. The link he  provided had the picture I posted, if he was wondering how to screw it on he probably would have used my picture showing the threaded part.